# vyatta virtual router interface aliasing does not work

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, vyatta, ip-aliasing

I am trying to create an alias on vyatta virtual router. But I do not seem to get it to work. In vyatta we have to just add another address to the interface to add an alias. But the interface is not listening or accepting any connection request. What could be the issue:

```
interfaces{
   ethernet eth1{
            x.x.x.x/23
            x.x.x.x/23
   }
}
```

But I do not see alias interface in the `ifconfig` output. Is there something else, that I need to be aware of? Is it the right way of configuring interface alias on vyatta?

I am able to connect to first IP address but not second IP address.

Answer (score 0):

To see interfaces use: "show interfaces" from the CLI.
To configure them use Vyatta´s configuration mode, not Linux.

To enter configuration mode: "configure"

set interfaces ethernet eth1 address 'x.x.x.x/23'
set interfaces ethernet eth1 description 'INSIDE'
commit
save

"exit" to exit configuration mode, then "show interfaces".

Take into account the correct use of LAN Segments, as well as routing.